# A question about the intersection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was doing a proof in which I figured out that $x \in \cup F$ and $x \notin \cup P(B)$. Can I say that $x \in \cup(F\setminus P(B))$ or is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x\in\cup(F\setminus P(B))$ iff there exists a set in $F$ which contains $x$ and is not in $P(B)$. So yes, this follows, because $x\in\cup F$ implies that 
there is a set $E\in F$ such that $x\in E$. Now $E\not\in P(B)$ because, if it were, then $x\in\cup P(B)$ would give a contradiction. Consequently $E\in F\setminus P(B)$ so that $x\in E \subseteq \cup(F\setminus P(B))$.